# Gluing schemes: Tips and tricks.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Like many other people I have talked to, I always find checking the cocycle condition quite hard and messy. I notice that most books avoid showing explicitly that the cocycle condition is satisfied, by either stating that it is obvious or giving it as an exercise to the reader, which suggests that the authors might not be too fond of doing this either.

My question is: Does anyone here know of some tips and tricks which makes this arduous task more comfortable?

At the moment I am only interested of the case of gluing schemes along open subschemes by the way.

Comment: I think the cocycle condition is often hidden behind some universal property or representable functor. To be honest, checking the details for those things is also not very fun and is also typically left to the reader. I do think it's on something of a higher level though.

Comment: If you're just checking representability of a functor then you can reduce the cocycle condition (which is a condition on triple intersections) to a somewhat easier condition on double intersections.

Comment: Keep practicing until you become better!  A couple years ago, it was probably tough to check that something was a homomorphism.  But you've done it enough now that you can see it right away.  The cocycle condition is important and you'll see it again in many places and then it will become easier.